# If B is half of A and C is half of B and the sum of all them is 1 then, what is A?

Tags: divisibility

If $B = A/2$, $C = B/2$, and $A + B + C = 1$, then what does $A$ equal?
I'm baffled trying to solve this question I made up for "my own purposes" and this problem is always a bit off when I try to solve it (Min. Found Distortion = 1/Infinity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ A + \tfrac{A}{2} + \tfrac{\;\tfrac{A}{2}\;}{2} = 1$$

$$ 4A + 2A + A = 4$$

$$ A = \tfrac{4}{7}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Then according to your definitions $$C=\frac A 4$$ and then you have that $$A+A/2+A/4=1$$